# Манипуляторы потоков. Разные манипуляторы потоков выдают одинаковый результат

Tags: c++

Для вывода числа с плавающей точкой, я могу использовать такие манипуляторы:

```
auto Smanip1 = std::fixed;
auto Smanip2 = std::setiosflags(
               std::ios_base::fixed | 
               std::ios_base::showpoint);
    //то же самое, но с одним флагом
auto Smanip3 = std::setiosflags(std::ios_base::fixed);
```

В чем будет различие, при использовании каждого из них?
Ведь, кажется они выдают одинаковый результат:

```
using std::cout;
cout << std::setprecision(3);
const double d = 12345.67789;   
cout << Smanip1  << d << std::endl;
cout.unsetf(std::ios_base::floatfield);
cout << Smanip2  << d << std::endl; 
std::cout << Smanip3  << d;
```

Во всех трех вариантах:    `12345.678`

Comment: чувствую подвох, но не могу понять где) даже стандарт посмотрел, там нет описания

Comment: подозреваю, что `std::fixed` и `std::ios_base::fixed` одно и тоже, а `std::ios_base::showpoint` по умолчанию всегда установлен, его можно только отключить скормив потоку `std::noshowpoint`

Comment: @goldstar_labs,  std::ios_base::fixed  это флаг _ имеющий перечисляемый тип   std::ios_base:: _Fmtflags, а  std::fixed это манипулятор(функция). Совершенно не одно и то же....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Флаг `showpoint` имеет какой-то эффект только в тех случаях, когда дробная часть числа не выводится (не выводилась бы).

- В формате `fixed` флаг `showpoint` имеет какой-то эффект только в формате `setprecision(0)`. В этом формате `showpoint` просто добавляет в вывод точку, без чего-либо после нее

  ```
  cout << fixed << setprecision(0);
  cout << 12.34 << endl;
  cout << showpoint;
  cout << 12.34 << endl;

  12
  12.
  ```
- В формате `defaultfloat` флаг `showpoint` имеет какой-то эффект только в случаях, когда дробная часть числа равна нулю. В этом формате при нулевой дробной части `showpoint` добавляет в вывод точку и дробную часть из нулей до достижения текущего precision. Это правило распространяется в том числе на формат вывода мантиссы в тех ситуациях, когда `defaultfloat` принимает решение переключиться в научный формат вывода

  ```
  cout << defaultfloat;
  cout << setprecision(3) << 1000. << endl;
  cout << setprecision(6) << 1000. << endl;
  cout << showpoint;
  cout << setprecision(3) << 1000. << endl;
  cout << setprecision(6) << 1000. << endl;

  1e+03
  1000
  1.00e+03
  1000.00
  ```

В вашем примере эти условия не выполняются, то есть точка и так выводится (выводилась бы). Явное указание `showpoint` ни на что дополнительно не влияет.

---

Правильным способом прямого выбора формата через флаги является вызов

```
std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield)
```

то есть нужно не забывать чистить все поле `floatfield`. Манипулятор `std::fixed` это делает. Манипулятор `std::setiosflags` не дает эквивалентной функциональности, ибо он не сбрасывает остальные флаги в `floatfield`. То есть ваши `Smanip2` и `Smanip3` могут вести себя неправильно, если флаг `fixed` "смешается" с каким-нибудь другим флагом `floatfield`.

Вам в вашем примере повезло, что флаги не "смешались" и `Smanip1` внешне ведет себя так же как и `Smanip3`. Но в общем случае это не одно и то же.

Comment: насколько я понел, в моем коде  Smanip3 и Smanip1    одно и то же?..Т.е. Smanip1  возвращает Smanip3?...

Comment: Все, я понел, спасибо!